# Export a specific data in an app in the django admin to a pdf

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

I've already set everything that is need to export a data to pdf format. Now, my problem is how can I do this use case to the django admin. Can I accomplish this by action whilst providing the class view then add that specific class view in the action to the modeladmin? Is that possible? How can I do this?

This is my class view

```
class PdfCarrier(View):

    def get(self, request, carrier_id):
        carrier = Carrier.objects.filter(id=carrier_id).first()
        params = {
        'today': timezone.now(),
        'carrier': carrier,
        'request': request
        }

        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "inline; filename=Carrier-Report.pdf"

        html = render_to_string('carrier/carrier_pdf.html', params)
        css = [
            base.BASE_DIR + '/src/css/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.min.css'
        ]

        HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response, stylesheets=css)
        return response
        # return Render.render('carrier/carrier_print.html', params)
```

my url providing it.

```
    path('<uuid:carrier_id>/carrier-report.pdf', views.PdfCarrier.as_view(), name="print_carrier"),
```

Answer (score 0):

That is possible. In your model admin class prepend the pdf path to the list of built-in urls.

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        custom_urls = [
            path('<uuid:carrier_id>/carrier-report.pdf', self.pdf_view),
        ]
        return custom_urls + urls
```

Then define the method `pdf_view` like below.

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def pdf_view(self, request, carrier_id):
        # do whatever you want
        # and return the response
```

That's it.